# How to sum javascript document.getElementsByName

Tags: javascript

Good day everyone! I am trying to sum all my fields using getElementsByName instead of ID because i have 3 textbox with the same name if i use the ID the first the textbox only will work and the rest is not working..

```
    var shirt1=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("shirt[]")[0].value);
    var shirt2=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("shirt[]")[1].value);
    var shirt3=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("shirt[]")[2].value);

    var combi1=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("combi[]")[0].value);
    var combi2=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("combi[]")[1].value);
    var combi3=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("combi[]")[2].value);

var collarcuff1=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("collarcuff[]")[0].value);
var collarcuff2=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("collarcuff[]")[1].value);
var collarcuff3=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("collarcuff[]")[2].value);

    var csp1=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("csp[]")[0].value);
    var csp2=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("csp[]")[1].value);
    var csp3=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("csp[]")[2].value);

    var totalValue = (shirt1 + combi1 + collarcuff1 + csp1).toFixed(2);

    document.getElementsByName("subtotal[]")[0].value = totalValue;
```

My HTML code is

```
<div style="height: 20px;">
<label style="display: inline-block !important;   padding-bottom: 5px;
      vertical-align: middle;float: left; font-weight: bold;">Shirt: </label>

<input style="float: right; margin-left: 8px;" type="text" name="shirt[]" autocomplete="off" id="shirt" pattern="^\d+(\.)\d{2}$" value="0.00"  onkeyup="getValues()" />
</div>

<br />

<div style="height: 20px;">
 <label style="display: inline-block !important;   padding-bottom: 5px;
vertical-align: middle;float: left; font-weight: bold;">Combi: </label>

<input style="float: right;" type="text" name="combi[]" autocomplete="off" id="combi" value="0.00" style="margin-left: 8px;" pattern="^\d+(\.)\d{2}$" onkeyup="getValues()"/>
</div>
 <br />

<div style="height: 20px;">
<label style="display: inline-block !important;   padding-bottom: 5px;
 vertical-align: middle;float: left; font-weight: bold;">Collar and Cuff: </label>

<input style="float: right;" type="text" name="collarcuff[]" autocomplete="off" id="collarcuff" style="margin-left: 8px;" value="0.00" pattern="^\d+(\.)\d{2}$"  onkeyup="getValues()"/>
</div>

 <br />

<div style="height: 20px;">
 <label style="display: inline-block !important;   padding-bottom: 5px;
vertical-align: middle;float: left; font-weight: bold;">CSP: </label>
 <input style="float: right;" type="text" name="cmp[]" autocomplete="off" id="csp" style="margin-left: 8px;" value="0.00" pattern="^\d+(\.)\d{2}$" onkeyup="getValues()" />

</div>

    <div style="height: 20px;">
    <label style="display: inline-block !important;   padding-bottom: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;float: left; font-weight: bold;">Sub-Total: </label>

    <input style="float: right;" type="text" name="subtotal[]" id="subtotal" value="0.00" style="margin-left: 8px;"  onkeyup="getValues()" />
    </div>
```

The sum of shirt1, combi1, collarcuff1 and csp1 should be added to subtotal. But its not displaying. But when i use Id to add them all its working why its not working in name? Please help me. THanks

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: Doing the lookup `document.getElementsByName("shirt[]")` over and over again is bad bad practice. Store it in a variable. Reference that variable

Comment: Are the `name`s of the `<input>`s all ending in `[]`, or did you add those in?

Comment: You really should learn about arrays and loops. I suggest to read http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#h_FaGGgUI+MM and http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html .

Comment: @torazaburo UM, what do you think the parseFloat is doing?

Comment: @epascarello my document.getElementsByName("shirt[]") has variable please look into it again.

Comment: @Somi Is there any errors in the developer console?

Comment: @Somi, no you did not understand what I meant. `var shirts = document.getElementsByName("shirt[]");
var shirt1=parseFloat( shirts[0].value );` Is what I am talking about. It will not fix your issue, just better performance.

Comment: @epascarello no error at all. How can i fix my issue?

Comment: I have no clue... I do not know what your problem is....

Comment: I tried to show the output using the alert and its working  but when i am trying to add them in subtotal there's no display.

Comment: Look at your developer console, you will have an error after you type.

Answer (score 1):

You do have an error in your console when you type and it is because you did not name your elements correctly.

```
"csp[]" !== "cmp[]"
```

your HTML

```
<input style="float: right;" type="text" name="cmp[]" autocomplete="off" id="csp" ...
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Your JavaScript

```
var csp1=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("csp[]")[0].value); 
                                                ^^^^^^^
```

---

```js
function getValues() {

  var shirts = document.getElementsByName("shirt[]"),
      combi = document.getElementsByName("combi[]"),
      collarcuff = document.getElementsByName("collarcuff[]"),
      csp = document.getElementsByName("csp[]"),
      subtotals = document.getElementsByName("subtotal[]"),  
      grandTotal = 0,
      i;
  for (i = 0; i < shirts.length; i++) {
    var subTotal = parseFloat(shirts[i].value) + parseFloat(combi[i].value) + parseFloat(collarcuff[i].value) + parseFloat(csp[i].value);
    subtotals[i].value = subTotal.toFixed(2);
    grandTotal+=subTotal;
  }
  document.getElementsByName("grandtotal")[0].value = grandTotal.toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 20%;
}
input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<label>S:</label>
<input type="text" value="0.00" name="shirt[]" onkeyup="getValues()" />
<label>CO:</label>
<input type="text" value="0.00" name="combi[]" onkeyup="getValues()" />
<label>CC:</label>
<input type="text" value="0.00" name="collarcuff[]" onkeyup="getValues()" />
<label>CSP:</label>
<input type="text" value="0.00" name="csp[]" onkeyup="getValues()" />
<label>ST:</label>
<input type="text" name="subtotal[]" readonly/>
<hr/>

<label>S:</label>
<input type="text" value="0.00" name="shirt[]" onkeyup="getValues()" />
<label>CO:</label>
<input type="text" value="0.00" name="combi[]" onkeyup="getValues()" />
<label>CC:</label>
<input type="text" value="0.00" name="collarcuff[]" onkeyup="getValues()" />
<label>CSP:</label>
<input type="text" value="0.00" name="csp[]" onkeyup="getValues()" />
<label>ST:</label>
<input type="text" name="subtotal[]" readonly/>
<hr/>

<label>S:</label>
<input type="text" value="0.00" name="shirt[]" onkeyup="getValues()" />
<label>CO:</label>
<input type="text" value="0.00" name="combi[]" onkeyup="getValues()" />
<label>CC:</label>
<input type="text" value="0.00" name="collarcuff[]" onkeyup="getValues()" />
<label>CSP:</label>
<input type="text" value="0.00" name="csp[]" onkeyup="getValues()" />
<label>ST:</label>
<input type="text" name="subtotal[]" readonly/>
<hr/>

<label>Grand Total</label>
<input type="text" name="grandtotal" readonly/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your eagle eyes but its still not working even without the csp i tried it now.

Comment: Did you change it to cmp?? Do you actually have three inputs of each type? Open up the developer tool, it has to tell you errors.

Comment: yeah i actually have 3 inputs. Its still not working though. I sum the shirt1 + combi1 no display still.

Comment: add alert statements between any two lines of your code :)

Comment: Yeah its well well but its not displaying the output here document.getElementsByName("subtotal[]")[0].value

Comment: "but its not displaying" - what does it mean? the line executes but the input stays empty?

Answer (score 0):

This is where the QSA is best used i.e.

```
var shirts = [];
var combi = [];
temp = document.querySelectorAll("name=shirt[]");
for( x=0; x<temp.length; x++ ) {
   shirts[x] = parseFloat(temp[x].value);
}
temp = document.querySelectorAll("name=combi[]");
for( x=0; x<temp.length; x++ ) {
   combi[x] = parseFloat(temp[x].value);
}

etc etc

shirt1 = shirts[0] + combi[0} + ....
```

Comment: Do you have other sample?

Comment: Your code has a typo as seen by the coloring in your post.